# Aggregate message by poll cycle

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a standard `Poller` connected to a `Channel`.

Every `n` seconds I'd like to poll at most `m` messages, aggregate them (they're just plain text) and send the result via FTP.

My problem is that the messages polled have `correlation-id=null` and hence I don't know how to aggregate them.

How can I "inject" into all the messages a `correlation-id` that is unique for every polling cycle so I can aggregate them?

Answer (score 1):

The aggregator can just accept any `CorrelationStrategy`, not only based on a `correlationId`. Sometimes I make it based on a `Thread.currentThread().getId()` and a `ReleaseStrategy` is for some number to gather in the aggregator.

What you are saying about the poller is really fit into the mentioned approach if you don't configure a task executor and let all the messages to be pull on a scheduled thread.

If this doesn't match your requirements, you indeed can come up with some random `correlationId` to be set into a message produced from this polling channel adapter.

For that purpose you need to look into a `ReceiveMessageAdvice` and implement its `beforeReceive()` the way to set a `ThreadLocal` variable into desired `correlationId` if it is not set yet.

In the `afterReceive()` you recreate a message setting the header based on a value from that `ThreadLocal` and clean up this `ThreadLocal` if message is `null`.

See more info about that advice in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/polling-consumer.html#smart-polling